# How to remove whitespace between two paragraphs?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, json, swift

[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRkZz.png)

I am getting data from Html to the text.
Now please tell me how to avoid the space between two paragraphs ?

```
  func processGetDescriptionResponse(json: JSON) {
    let status = json.dictionaryObject!["status"] as? Bool
    if status == true {
        let data = json.dictionaryValue["data"]!
        let values = data.arrayValue
        dataSourceDescription.removeAll()
        for i in 0 ..< values.count {
            let description = Description.initWithJSON(values[i])
            dataSourceDescription.append(description)
```

//                DetailDescription.text =  dataSourceDescription[i].content

```
            if dataSourceDescription[i].file_url == ""
            {
                DetailImage.image = UIImage(named: "logo_two_fifty")
            }
            else
            {
            let imageURL = NSURL(string: baseURLString + dataSourceDescription[i].file_url!)


            DetailImage.kf_setImageWithURL(imageURL!, placeholderImage: nil, optionsInfo: [.Transition(ImageTransition.Fade(50))]) { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in
                }

            }


            DetailDescription.attributedText = convertText(dataSourceDescription[i].content!)


            print(DetailDescription.text)
        }

    } else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you receive html content, you can display it in `UITextView` using `NSAttributedString`:

```
let htmlString = "<html><body><p>Para 1</p><p>Para 2</p></body></html>"

let attributedString = try!
    NSAttributedString(data: htmlString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUnicodeStringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!,
                       options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                       documentAttributes: nil)

yourTextView.attributedText = attributedString
```